# Emissions material that is glittery?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, workflow

Is it possible to create a glittery material that is emissions-only, that has "shadowy" areas and depth?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The material might be a mix of these, or just one of these.  I would be happy to just have a starting point, for a glittery emissions material!

Comment: Can you add an image that illustrates what you are after?

Comment: I think this is a nice question. My first instinct would be to use a voronoi texture but this is not constant over a certain area, and cannot be made constant just by math nodes.

Comment: The pictures show a material thats not emissive but rather glossy with a bump. Is it required for it to be emission only inside Blender? I.e. only use emission nodes? Are we talking cycles?

Comment: @AdamTM Yes, I am using cycles.  I would like for the glittery sparkle to exist and *shimmer* as the object moves, without being dependent on a light source to do so.  So the shimmer itself would be generated by the material, but the material would still behave as a non-emissions material by having shadowy areas in the indentions, or at least a different, darker color in the indentions and along contours.  The contours and indentions of the mesh would still be evident and clear.  Can a material behave as as emissions and behave as non-emissions at the same time?

Comment: @AdamTM  I guess the intensity and/or color of the sparkle would depend on where the contours of the mesh are.  I am relatively new to nodes so I cannot speak in more detail than this right now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the same technique as in your glossy question, here is what i think would work:

[image]

Additionally you would maybe need a tilable image texture to make this work better than vornoi.
The glow like in the reference picture is post processed in with nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a texture as a mask for displace and emission, with a `coloramp` for tuning: It will look better with `true displace` on
[image]

Have a look at the node setup. Cheers.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for but it looks interesting and I will try it !